# how to disable dates in date picker when select a date in other datepicker

Tags: java, swing, date, datepicker

i have 2 datepickers show in the image.

here first i select **issuedate** then the **returndate** datepicker shows the **dates after the isuue dates**. The **issuedate to backword dates are not visible for return datepicker**

[image]

the code for datepicker...

```
        JLabel lblIssueDate = new JLabel("Issue Date");
        lblIssueDate.setBounds(85, 47, 137, 14);
        issuePanel.add(lblIssueDate);

        issueDate = new JXDatePicker();
        java.util.Date utilDate=new Date();
        java.sql.Date sqldate=new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
        issueDate.setDate(sqldate);
        issueDate.setBounds(232, 44, 184, 20);
        issuePanel.add(issueDate);

        JLabel lblReturnDate = new JLabel("Return Date");
        lblReturnDate.setBounds(85, 113, 137, 14);
        issuePanel.add(lblReturnDate);

        returnDate = new JXDatePicker();
        returnDate.setBounds(232, 110, 184, 20);
        issuePanel.add(returnDate);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Basically, you can set the upper and lower acceptable bounds of the date picker via its `JXMonthView`.  This will restrict the dates that the user can pick

For example...

[image: DatePicker]

```
import java.awt.BorderLayout;
import java.awt.EventQueue;
import java.awt.GridBagConstraints;
import java.awt.GridBagLayout;
import java.awt.event.ActionEvent;
import java.awt.event.ActionListener;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeEvent;
import java.beans.PropertyChangeListener;
import java.util.Date;
import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JLabel;
import javax.swing.JPanel;
import javax.swing.UIManager;
import javax.swing.UnsupportedLookAndFeelException;
import org.jdesktop.swingx.JXDatePicker;

public class TestDatePicker {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        new TestDatePicker();
    }

    public TestDatePicker() {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                try {
                    UIManager.setLookAndFeel(UIManager.getSystemLookAndFeelClassName());
                } catch (ClassNotFoundException | InstantiationException | IllegalAccessException | UnsupportedLookAndFeelException ex) {
                }

                JFrame frame = new JFrame("Testing");
                frame.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
                frame.setLayout(new BorderLayout());
                frame.add(new TestPane());
                frame.pack();
                frame.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
                frame.setVisible(true);
            }
        });
    }

    public class TestPane extends JPanel {

        private JXDatePicker issueDate;
        private final JXDatePicker returnDate;

        public TestPane() {
            setLayout(new GridBagLayout());
            GridBagConstraints gbc = new GridBagConstraints();
            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy = 0;

            JLabel lblIssueDate = new JLabel("Issue Date");
            add(lblIssueDate, gbc);

            issueDate = new JXDatePicker();
            returnDate = new JXDatePicker();

            issueDate.addPropertyChangeListener("date", new PropertyChangeListener() {
                @Override
                public void propertyChange(PropertyChangeEvent evt) {
                    System.out.println("date");
                    Date selectedDate = issueDate.getDate();
                    returnDate.getMonthView().setLowerBound(selectedDate);
                }
            });
            java.util.Date utilDate = new Date();
            java.sql.Date sqldate = new java.sql.Date(utilDate.getTime());
            issueDate.setDate(sqldate);
            gbc.gridx++;
            add(issueDate, gbc);

            gbc.gridx = 0;
            gbc.gridy++;
            JLabel lblReturnDate = new JLabel("Return Date");
            add(lblReturnDate, gbc);

            gbc.gridx++;
            add(returnDate, gbc);
        }
    }

}
```

Now if you want to be able to pick the dates BEFORE the `IssueDate`, you can use `setUpperBound` instead.

If you want to exclude the selected date as well, then you need to use a `Calendar` and roll it by a day in the required direction to included it...

I would also highly recommend make use of appropriate layout managers as they will deal with the variety of differences between systems and how fonts are renderer, amongst other things.

Swing is also designed to work with layout managers, so choosing to ignore them can have lots of funny side effects...

Take a look at [Laying Out Components Within a Container](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/layout/index.html)